# В ЯП Pascal выполнялось задача нахождение площади "Кольца"

Tags: pascal

Написав код, в результате всегда выводится значение `0`. В чём заключается моя ошибка?

Код

```
program coltso;
  var t, D, R, s, pi: real;
 begin
   pi:=3.14;
   write('Введите диаметр внутреннего круга d>>');
   readln(d);
   write('Введите толщину t>>');
   readln(t);
   r:=d/2;
   R:=r+t;
   s:=pi*((R*R)-(r*r));
   writeln(s);
 end.
```

В Изображении показан результат при значении `d= 6, t = 1`.
[image]

Comment: Вставьте картинку целиком, а не по ссылке (в редакторе есть специальная кнопка)

Comment: Учитесь давать переменным понятные имена.

Comment: Забавно, что автора вопроса совершенно не насторожило, что переменную `r` он не объявил, а оно работает :) Не надо мне только рассказывать о чувствительности Pascal к регистру - автор-то считал, что он чувствителен...

Answer (score 1):

Потому что `X - X` будет нуль.

```pascal
((R*R)-(r*r))
```

Паскаль не различает `R` и `r`,
для него это одна переменная.